# Swift Overload NSDecimalNumber operators

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm wondering if there is a reason Swift doesn't just overload the standard arithmetic (+,-,*,<,> etc.) operators for `NSDecimalNumber`, and instead  opts for traditional methods with names like `adding`, `subtracting` etc.

I'd like to overload these operators, is this a good idea, what are the potential drawbacks?

**EDIT**

Apparently Swift 3 added a `Decimal` type. Swift 3 also dropped NS in front of a bunch of other types so I assumed `Decimal` was just an `NSDecimal` with the NS dropped, but this is not the case! Although it doesn't really answer the question, I think using `Decimal` instead of `NSDecimalNumber` should usually be a good response going forward for Swift 3 and later. One reason you may want to stick with `NSDecimalNumber` is if you have many extensions and don't want to bridge every time you want to use extension methods.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. Go for it and report back with your results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you though about using `Decimal` instead of `NSDecimalNumber`?

```
let d1 = Decimal(integerLiteral: 10)
let d2 = Decimal(integerLiteral: 2)
let result = d1 * d2 // 20
```

Comment: context: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/1ff21546037a86e4cc89ebe5fd0e0c738cd234c8/stdlib/public/SDK/Foundation/Decimal.swift#L128-L158

Comment: I'm working with currencies, so I'd like to stick with NSDecimalNumber

Comment: @Alex Decimal is the NSDecimalNumber equivalent in Swift.

Comment: Code Data still uses NSDecimalNumber in the generated classes

Answer (score 0):

I have to retain the old NSDecimalValue to use with Core Data. I wanted to be able to use comparisons, so I added this extension:

```
extension NSDecimalNumber: Comparable { // Comparable adds <=, >=, and > 

  public static func ==(lhs: NSDecimalNumber, rhs: NSDecimalNumber) -> Bool {
    return lhs.compare(rhs) == .orderedSame
  }

  public static func <(lhs: NSDecimalNumber, rhs: NSDecimalNumber) -> Bool {
    return lhs.compare(rhs) == .orderedAscending
  }

}
```